# How can I find my google drive service account usage limits?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-api-java-client

I created service account to consume Google Drive REST API for domain wide delegation. But from document I came to know that there are some limits API consumption such as

1. Number of request per day per app.
2. Number of requests/second/user etc.

Now my questions are

1. How can I find these exact numbers of my google service account?
2. What are default numbers for free account?
3. Is these numbers vary from service account and install app type applications?

Can anyone one help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each request to the Google API will be counted. You can monitor your quota details from [Google Developer Console](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/apis/library?project=premium-portal-118702&debugUI=DEVELOPERS).

`APIs & Auth -> APIs -> Select the API -> Navigate to Quota tab`.

Currently for the Drive API it reads "Courtesy limit: 1,000,000,000 requests/day". It's a per app quota.

After you've enabled the Drive API you can also set a per user rate limit (by default 100 req/sec) to prevent one user from depleting your app's quota. That's available in the "Quotas" tab.

There is also a link to request more quota in the "Quotas" tab in case you need more than the default 1B req/day.